# Set up current Album 'pk' in genericView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm trying to delete `object (foto)` from `Album` and I want `views` to return to `detail view` (current Album) but I can't set up `pk` of current Album . I tried various ways but I can't figure it out and solve it. 
Maybe I should add some independent `foto_pk` for foto's objects, or instead of generic `DeleteView` use some usual definition?  I'm out of ideas. Please give me some clues... Thanks.

**URLs:**

```
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

url(r'albumadd/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),

url(r'update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='albumbum-update'),

url(r'delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='albumbum-delete'),

url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/fotoadd/$', views.FotoCreate.as_view(), name='foto-add'),

url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/fotodelete/$', views.FotoDelete.as_view(), name='foto-delete'),
```

**Views:**

```
class FotoDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Foto

    def album(request, pk):
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return reverse_lazy('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': album.pk})
```

other try Views:

```
class FotoDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Foto
    success_url = reverse_lazy('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': Album.pk})
```

other try Views:

```
class FotoDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Foto
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=pk)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': album.pk})
```

also I append CreateView of foto (objects in album): 
(maybe here is something that casing that problem)

```
class FotoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Foto
    fields = ['nazwa_foto', 'obraz']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = Album.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        form.instance.albumnr = f
        return super(FotoCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs.get('pk')})
```

models.py

```
class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nazwa_albumu = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="nazwa Albumu")
    temat = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="temat")
    opis_albumu = models.TextField(max_length=2000, default="opis")
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="link http:// do logo")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa_albumu + ' - ' + str(self.user)


class Foto(models.Model):
    albumnr = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nazwa_foto = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='nazawa foto')
    obraz = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='link http:// do obrazu')

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa_foto
```

Comment: Please include `models.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work.

```
class FotoDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Foto

    def get_success_url(self):
         fotoid = self.kwargs['pk']
         foto = get_object_or_404(Foto, id=fotoid)
         album_id = foto.albumnr.pk
         return reverse_lazy('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': album_id})
```

Comment: It's not working.Redirect me to `/albumbum/31/fotodelete/None` (Page not found) and 31 is `pk` of foto, but I need to redirect me to `/albumbum/2` where 2 is my Album `pk`. When I set up manually `kwargs={'pk': 2 }` it works in all casses, but that's the issue, how to retrieve 'album.pk' from level of that album's object.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if it works. It should work though.

Comment: Yes, that works indeed, but I want to redirect me after delete object from album, to the same album (really I want to stay at the same album page during deleting an object) and your solution redirect me to index where all albums are, not `albumbum:detail` and there I need put some `pk` of that album.

Comment: You can't do that coz you are using the `pk` to delete so once `pk` is deleted you can not use same `pk` to go to detail.

Comment: Please include `models.py`.

Comment: @WitoldKrzemiński, I have misunderstood your question early. Sorry for that, but I have updated answer now, check it, now it should work fine.

Comment: `foto = get_object_or_404(Foto, pk=PK)` - my API promt says "name `PK` is not defined" and marks also `album` from `album_id = foto.album.pk` - "unresolved attribute reference 'album' for class Foto" :(

Comment: `foto = get_object_or_404(Foto, id=pk)`,  still the same - "name `pk` is not defined" (Unresolved reference 'pk') - maybe is that because of this generic DeleteView...

Comment: Please have a check now, and let me know.

Comment: `foto = get_object_or_404(Foto, id=kwargs['pk'])` still the same but with `kwargs`now

Comment: So, only thing we need to figure out now is `pk` of foto that is getting deleted and everything will work fine. Give me some time let me figure out.

Comment: @WitoldKrzemiński, I have updated my code, please check once more. I think this time it should work.

Comment: Success! I added only to your code `return reverse` and it start working, without that - Page not found 404. Thank You my friend. You are very, very good person. Probably without You I would't solve that, on my own. You are awesome!

Comment: yeah sorry `return` was needed. I forgot.

Comment: I feel privileged to help you. You are very cooperative and patient and waited all that long. Thanks for being.

Comment: You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

That works also:

```
class FotoDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Foto

    def get_success_url(self):
        fotoid = self.kwargs['pk']
        foto = get_object_or_404(Foto, pk=fotoid)
        album_id = foto.albumnr.pk
        return reverse('albumbum:detail', kwargs={'pk': album_id})
```